# Which is most effective way to add parameters to JSON Volley request?

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I have simple app witch set of data about beers from api.
I want to write way to set four parameters via alert dialog and it looks like my way is kind of primitive and complicated, it looks like:

```
private String createFilteredUrl() {
    String queryEndpoint = "?";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(alcFromV != 0){
        sb.append("abv_gt=" + alcFromV);
    }
    if(alcToV != 0){
        sb.append("abv_lt=" + alcToV);
    }
    if(ibuFromV != 0){
        sb.append("ibu_gt=" + ibuFromV);
    }
    if(ibuToV != 0){
        sb.append("ibu_lt=" + ibuToV);
    }
  return queryEndpoint;

}
```

it's only partially done, because I thought this is so inefficient way and there mus be some simpler solution developed. Here I should actually rewrite if statements conditions, because if user skip one field than I have to ignore one of parameters, and so on, there will be a lot of if statements and whole code won't look very clean

so, this is the way I'm supposed to do my request with parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Volley then why don't you use its `getParams()` override method

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            headerParams.put("key1", "val1");
            headerParams.put("key2", "val2");
            ..............
            return params;
        }
```

Comment: I've read that this method ic called only when POST type request is made, not GET, is this not true?

Comment: You can try it as for few request getParams() works and for few methods it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `alcFromV` ,  `alcToV` ,  `ibuFromV` e.t.c in an array, replace the if statements with a for or for-each statement and itterate through the contents of the array.

Still primitive but less primitive! ;)